# Saving Bitmap drawn on Canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, colormatrixfilter

In my application I extended the ImageView and overriden its onDraw() method. I am using a color filter to manipulate the bitmap for adding some effects like invert, grayscale etcc. After drawing the bitmap I am trying to save it but I am only able to save the original bitmap with no added effects. Here is the code for onDraw() and save method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    //cmf is the color matrix filter
    paint.setColorFilter(cmf);

    if(mBitmap != null)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, offsetW, offsetH, paint);
    }
}
```

code for saving the bitmap:

```
 try
        {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path);

            mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fout);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be appretiated.

Comment: try by calling method invalidate()

Comment: why save the bitmap at all ? you could instead save the paints, if they vary a lot, and reuse them. If you save many bitmaps you might run into memory trouble

Comment: @jay onDraw() method is called so there is no need to call invalidate().

Comment: @NikkyD I am saving the bitmap only when the user clicks on the save button. So, memory is not a problem here. The problem is saving the effects drawn on the bitmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are painting on the canvas that is displayed, original bitmap is not changed. You should create a new bitmap and paint on it. When color matrix filter changes do this:

```
Bitmap tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mBitmap.getConfig())
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tmp)
cnvas.drawBitmap(tmp, 0, 0, paint);
```

Then, you can use this tmp bitmap to draw it and save it.

Instead of using customized `ImageView` use a normal one and set its image to this new bitmap:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(tmp)
```

Comment: that's true...I have tried this solution but when I use setBitmap() and drawBitmap() combination then nothing is displayed on the screen. The screen remains blank. That's why I am not using setBitmap(). I don't know the reason but that's what is happeing.

Comment: What do you mean by `setBitmap()`? What do you call this on? In `onDraw()` just call `canvas.drawBitmap(tmp, offsetW, offsetH, paint);` See my updated answer.