# Saved bitmap doesn't display the lines drawn over it

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have tried the following links - [draw-on-a-canvas-with-bitmap-as-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518387/draw-on-a-canvas-with-bitmap-as-background/14518974#14518974) and [saving-bitmap-drawn-on-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815694/saving-bitmap-drawn-on-canvas)

The first one worked for me and solved the problem allowing me to not only draw over bitmap image but allowing to save as well with the drawn lines.

Recently, I messed up with the layout and things are back to as they were. No solution despite days of struggle i.e. it saves the bitmap image but whatever is drawn on it doesn't show up in the image. The same code but still doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Below is my code:

```
class MyView extends View
   {
   public MyView(Context context)
   {
       super(context);
       paint = new Paint();
       paint.setDither(true);
       paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       paint.setColor(Color.RED);

       cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        canvas=new Canvas();
       path = new Path();
       paths = new ArrayList<>();

       opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       opt.inMutable = true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
       super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

       opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       opt.inMutable = true;

       bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.fabialeft, opt);
       bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
       bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp);
       canvas = new Canvas(bmp2);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, paint);
       for(Path p:paths)
           canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
   }

   public void Save() {
       directory =  cw.getDir("final", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       file = new File(directory,"fabialeft");
       FileOutputStream fos = null;
       try {
               fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
               bmp2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                   System.out.println("Saved to --" + file);
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               fos.close();
       }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
       {
           System.out.println(e);
           System.out.println("Saved" + file);
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "FNF EXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }catch (IOException ioe)
       {
           System.out.println("ERROR" + file);Toast.makeText(getContext(), "IO EXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

   }

   public void Draw() {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DRAWING...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       path.moveTo(100, 100);
       path.lineTo(300, 300);
       paths.add(path);
       invalidate();
   }

 }
```

Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relayout1"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Draw"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you confused your `bmp` and `bmp2` variables somehow (you should use better names...).

Here you define `bmp2` as bitmap for the canvas

```
canvas = new Canvas(bmp2);
```

but in `onDraw()` you somewhat try to paint the canvas's bitmap onto itself.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, paint);
```

I guess, you should use `bmp` here instead of `bmp2`.

Comment: Did you try that? I just did and that didn't solve the problem either, unfortunately.